# Could you provide an example for a nonreduced local ring with reducible Spectrum?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

As the title says, could you provide a local ring which is nonreduced and its $Spec$ is reducible?

It's one of the exercise in the Wedhorn's book.

To get a local ring I only need to do localization at a prime ideal, and to make it nonreduced I need to quotient some ideal. But it seems hard to ensure the reducibility of the Spec of that ring when the first two conditions are satisfied...

I have tried something like $(k[X,Y,Z]/(X^2,Y^2))_{(X,Y,Z)}$. It satisfies the first two condition, but it has a generic point $(X,Y)$ hence irreducible.

Could you provide some examples for this?

Comment: You're really quite close - do you know any examples of rings with reducible spectra? How can you imitate that here?

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your hint. The product of two such local rings can give a reducible spectra. But the product is no longer local, and if I do localization again it wouldn't be reducible. Is the product that you mean? Could you help me with my confusion? Thanks!

Comment: You're right, a product of rings would be inappropriate - what about a product of variables?

Comment: @KReiser Ah, I see, $(k[X,Y,Z]/(X^2,YZ))_{(X,Y,Z)}$ would work. Thanks!